# SQL meta-related queries

Tags: mysql, sql

hello i have 2 tables in mysql the table post and the table post_meta
I want to query the post table based on post_meta key/value data.
The first query in example with = statment is working , the second query with != statment not working. Any help?

**How its possible to exclude posts with postmeta key[hide] = value['1'] ?**

here the  expecting results

[image]

*example*

**//Show post where postmeta key[hide] = value[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7KBg.jpg)**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    post AS mt0
INNER JOIN post_meta AS mt1 ON mt0.id = mt1.postid
WHERE
    (
        mt1.`key` = 'hide'
        AND CAST(mt1.`value` AS CHAR) = 1
    )
```

**2 rows**
1   Post test 1 3   1   hide    1

3   Post test 3 4   3   hide    1

**//Show post where postmeta key[hide] != value[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7KBg.jpg)**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    post AS mt0
INNER JOIN post_meta AS mt1 ON mt0.id = mt1.postid
WHERE
    (
        mt1.`key` = 'hide'
        AND CAST(mt1.`value` AS CHAR) != 1
    )
```

**0 rows**

//why? this query must return the post 2

DB schema

```
----table post

CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('1', 'Post test 1');
INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('2', 'Post test 2');
INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('3', 'Post test 3');


----table post_meta

CREATE TABLE `post_meta` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `postid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `post_meta` VALUES ('1', '1', 'name', 'leone');
INSERT INTO `post_meta` VALUES ('2', '2', 'name', 'mario');
INSERT INTO `post_meta` VALUES ('3', '1', 'hide', '1');
INSERT INTO `post_meta` VALUES ('4', '3', 'hide', '1');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd query does not work because of the condition

```
mt1.`key` = 'hide'
```

Have a close look at the query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    post AS mt0
INNER JOIN post_meta AS mt1 ON mt0.id = mt1.postid
WHERE
    (
        mt1.`key` = 'hide'
        AND CAST(mt1.`value` AS CHAR) != 1
    )
```

You have a condition as

```
mt1.`key` = 'hide'
```

Then you are using

```
AND CAST(mt1.`value` AS CHAR) != 1
```

Now in the `post_meta` table check there is no data with

```
key = hide and value != '1'
```

Hence the condition fails and you get 0 result

Here is what you provided

```
INSERT INTO `post_meta` VALUES ('1', '1', 'name', 'leone');
INSERT INTO `post_meta` VALUES ('2', '2', 'name', 'mario');
INSERT INTO `post_meta` VALUES ('3', '1', 'hide', '1');
INSERT INTO `post_meta` VALUES ('4', '3', 'hide', '1');
```

With the update provided in the question you can get the result as

```
SELECT *
FROM
post AS mt0
INNER JOIN post_meta mt1
ON mt0.id = mt1.postid
AND mt0.id NOT IN (
  select postid from post_meta where `key` = 'hide' AND CAST(`value` AS CHAR) = 1
);
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/372cb/29)**

Comment: Thanks Abhik for the answer. How its possible to exclude post with postmeta hide = 1 ?

Comment: You welcome ! I did not get could you please add the result that you are expecting in the question. That will be easier for me to visualize it.

Comment: no,  i want to exclude also and post with id 1 why this post has postmeta.key[hide] = 1